# Postgresql (9.6) Select records with ILIKE ALL but excluding some words

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

I need to search on a cars table in my postgresql database matching ALL of some keywords, but excluding some of other keywords... for example... I need to find all cars which contain 'c4' AND 'citroen' on its slug, but which do not contain the words 'picasso' OR 'grand'.

I've tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM cars.cars 
WHERE slug ILIKE ALL (array['%citroen%','%c4%']) 
AND slug NOT ILIKE ANY (array['%picasso%','%grand%'])
```

It finds only which contains citroen AND c4, but does not excludes the records which contains picasso OR grand.

Answer (score 1):

Change ANY to ALL in the second where condition.
Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cars.cars 
WHERE slug ILIKE ALL (array['%citroen%','%c4%']) 
AND slug NOT ILIKE ALL (array['%picasso%','%grand%'])
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, it worked fine, but What's the difference between ANY and ALL then?

Comment: Think of NOT ALL = ANY and NOT ANY = ALL.